# A WinAPI C++ program for printing the master boot record of the hard drive

Tags: c++, winapi

I have rolled this program for reading the MBR:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using std::isprint;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::move;
using std::size_t;
using std::string;

constexpr size_t MBR_SIZE = 512;
constexpr size_t BYTES_PER_LINE = 4;
constexpr size_t NUMBER_OF_LINES = MBR_SIZE / BYTES_PER_LINE;

// Converts 4 least significant bits of 'c' to corresponding 
// hexadecimal string.
static string fourBitsToString(char c)
{
    string s = " ";

    if (c >= 0 && c <= 9) {
        s[0] = '0' + c;
    } else {
        c -= 10;
        s[0] = 'A' + c;
    }

    return move(s);
}

// Converts a character to its hexadecimal representation.
static string charToHex(char c)
{
    char lo = c & 0xf;
    char hi = (c >> 4) & 0xf;
    string s;
    char chars[] = {hi, lo};

    for (char ch : chars) {
        s += fourBitsToString(ch);
    }

    return std::move(s);
}

// Prints the MBR to console.
static void PrintMBR(char buffer[MBR_SIZE])
{
    size_t byteIndex = 0;
    string lineSeparator;
    string columnSeparator;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++) {
        cout << lineSeparator;
        lineSeparator = '\n';
        columnSeparator = "";

        for (size_t j = 0; j < BYTES_PER_LINE; j++) {
            string ch = charToHex(buffer[byteIndex++]);
            cout << columnSeparator << ch;
            columnSeparator = " ";
        }

        cout << ' ';

        for (size_t j = 0; j < BYTES_PER_LINE; j++) {
            char c = buffer[byteIndex - BYTES_PER_LINE + j];
            cout << (isprint((unsigned int) c) ? c : '.');
        }
    }
}

// Reads the entire master boot record (MBR) into lpBuffer. 
// Expects lpBuffer to point to a memory point that may     
// hold at leasst 512 bytes.                                
static DWORD ReadMBR(PCHAR lpBuffer)
{

    HANDLE diskHandle = CreateFile(
        TEXT("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    char* buffer = new char[MBR_SIZE];

    ReadFile(
        diskHandle,
        lpBuffer,
        MBR_SIZE,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    return GetLastError();
}

int main() {
    char buffer[MBR_SIZE];
    ReadMBR(buffer);
    PrintMBR(buffer);
    cin.get();
    return 3;
}
```

(Compile as `Release` instead of `Debug` if it throws a nasty runtime breakpoint.)

I would love to hear any comments possible, but my main question is whether it is  idiomatic C/C++/WinAPI.

**Note:** To see the actual MBR, run this as administrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `fourBitsToString` and `charToHex`

Both of these functions are basically reimplementations of existing features of the `<iostream>` and `<iomanip>` headers.

The whole call to `charToHex` could simply be replaced by `std::cout << std::uppercase << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(c);`.

> Note the `static_cast<int>`: We want to print the numerical value, not the ASCII character glyph!

However, setting `std::uppercase`, `std::hex` and `std::setfill('0')` for every byte to be printed would be wasteful, plus it would overwrite any previously set flags on `std::cout`.

A better approach would be using a intermediary `std::ostringstream` instead, setting the flags once and retrieving (and resetting) its contents when sufficiently filled.

> More on that in the section below.

Also, both functions end with `return move(s);`. This seems like misguided premature optimization ("Hey, we can move here! No need for a copy!"), but it likely is actually a pessimization instead!

Compilers actually know that the returned value is a temporary and can optimize for this case (usually called NRVO - "Named return value optimization"). But: They can only do this if the variable is returned directly, and the call to `std::move` prevents that.

Prefer `return s;`, unless you have good reasons (e.g. measurements/bad compiler) indicating otherwise.

## `PrintMBR`

This function is a big pile of unnecessarily complicated code with poorly documented/enfored preconditions.

First off, let's take a look at the function signature:

```
static void PrintMBR(char buffer[MBR_SIZE])
```

The flaw is really subtle: `buffer` isn't actually restricted to arrays of size `MBR_SIZE` at all! It's basically just a slightly fancier markup of `static void PrintMBR(char *buffer)`, and the compiler will actually treat it as such.

This allows `PrintMBR` to be called with `char` arrays of all possible sizes, including smaller than `MBR_SIZE`, or even just `nullptr`.

> How to fix this?
>
> Well, the first inclination might be to just limit the size of `buffer` by explicitly making it keep track of the size information, e.g. by using a reference to a C-style array `char (&buffer)[MBR_SIZE]` or a fancier `std::array` reference `const std::array<char, MBR_SIZE> &buffer`.
>
> And that is a valid option if the only purpose was to print MBR contents.
>
> But looking at it's actually implementation, it seems like the intention was to print the hex values in one big column next to a column containing to the ASCII characters (if printable) nicely aligned. This could be generalized for printing arbitrary `char` arrays by amending some of the assumptions made further down in the implementation.

Next, let's have a look at the function body:

```
size_t byteIndex = 0;
string lineSeparator;
string columnSeparator;

for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++) {
    cout << lineSeparator;
    lineSeparator = '\n';
    columnSeparator = "";

    for (size_t j = 0; j < BYTES_PER_LINE; j++) {
        string ch = charToHex(buffer[byteIndex++]);
        cout << columnSeparator << ch;
        columnSeparator = " ";
    }

    cout << ' ';

    for (size_t j = 0; j < BYTES_PER_LINE; j++) {
        char c = buffer[byteIndex - BYTES_PER_LINE + j];
        cout << (isprint((unsigned int) c) ? c : '.');
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, the intention is to print the MBR in a `XX XX XX XX xxxx` line format (where `X` is a hex digit and `x` is an ASCII character).

First off, it's hard to keep track of "constants" if their values are constantly changing. With one more check and a tiny bit of reordering, we can fix this:

```
size_t byteIndex = 0;
static const string lineSeparator = "\n";
static const string columnSeparator = " ";

for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++) {
    if(i != 0) cout << lineSeparator;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < BYTES_PER_LINE; j++) {
        string ch = charToHex(buffer[byteIndex++]);
        cout << ch << columnSeparator;
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < BYTES_PER_LINE; j++) {
        char c = buffer[byteIndex - BYTES_PER_LINE + j];
        cout << (isprint((unsigned int) c) ? c : '.');
    }
}
```

A bit more readable, and I don't have to keep track of all the possible states (and weird reassignments).

I mentioned above that instead of using `charToHex`, one could use `std::ostringstream` and `<iomanip>` facilities instead:

```
void PrintMBR(char (&buffer)[MBR_SIZE]) {
    static constexpr auto bytes_per_line = 4;
    static const auto column_delimiter = " "s;
    static const auto line_delimiter = "\n"s;

    auto hex_part = std::ostringstream{};
    auto ascii_part = std::ostringstream{};
    auto counter = 0;

    hex_part << std::uppercase << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

    for(auto c : buffer)
    {
        hex_part << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(c) << column_delimiter;
        ascii_part << (isprint(static_cast<unsigned int>(c)) ? c : '.');

        ++counter;

        if(counter % bytes_per_line == 0)
        {
            std::cout << hex_part.str() << ascii_part.str() << line_delimiter;
            hex_part.str("");
            ascii_part.str("");
        }
    }
}
```

> This could easily be made more generic to allow printing any byte buffer in this format.

## `ReadMBR`

- Memory leak: `buffer` doesn't ever get used after being allocated, including being deleted.
- I don't like the `return GetLastError();` bit. I guess it's fine in pure C, but in C++ there is a more common way to communicate error conditions: exceptions.

  I get this is kind of a glue layer between C WinAPI and C++, but that doesn't mean you have to port idioms from one side into the other, especially if there are more idiomatic alternatives.

  > I see this as problematic in this case, as likely nobody checks return codes unless they have to. Case in point: `main()`.
- To be more generic, I would really like for this method to accept an `OutputIterator`. But sadly, the C WinAPI doesn't know those, so that would require another copy of the data (using an intermediary buffer). That's one of the design trade-offs: Performance vs. Usability.

## `main`

- No check on the return code of `ReadMBR`.
- `return 3;` - What does this `3` represent?

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Accepted after the first 3 paragraphs.

Comment: Do note that guaranteed copy elision [does not extend to NRVO](https://godbolt.org/z/Dxq02b). Named object is glvalue, whereas the elision guarantees only cases with prvalues. I actually was not sure myself, had to spend some time to figure out. Great review otherwise.

Comment: @hoffmale, they certainly can be returned by value (commenting first two lines and uncommenting last line will make the code compile). It was just a little objection, but I believe it is important. [Link to RVO version](https://godbolt.org/z/R6OsRT). I believe mandatory copy elision is very different from compiler extension, as it allows slightly different techniques to be used. Perhaps I didn't communicate my intent correctly: the post mentions that mandatory copy elision extends to NRVO, but it is not the case, which I'm trying to prove.

Comment: @Incomputable: After reading up elsewhere it finally clicked what it was you wanted to show me, and you're correct. Fixed that part of the answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

Idiomatic is relative. I guess it's a coding style you could find in older code-bases (and many winapi based applications are rather old), but you wouldn't write C++ like this today. Consider for instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>

constexpr std::size_t MBR_SIZE = 255;
constexpr std::size_t BYTES_PER_COLUMN = 4;
constexpr char LINE_DELIMITER = '\n';
constexpr const char* COL_DELIMITER = " ";

int main() {
    std::array<unsigned char, MBR_SIZE> mbr;
    std::iota(std::begin(mbr), std::end(mbr), 0); // filling it for testing purposes

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    std::size_t index = 0;
    std::transform(std::begin(mbr), std::end(mbr), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, COL_DELIMITER), [index](auto c) mutable {
        if (index++ % BYTES_PER_COLUMN == 0) std::cout << LINE_DELIMITER;
        std::cout << std::setw(2); // setw must be applied for each output
        return c;
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In a dozen of lines you get the same result as `printMBR` and its two auxiliary functions (at least I believe so, I haven't had the chance to run your code), which are longer and more complicated.

To be more specific about your code:

- don't declare a variable before you're ready to define it, and don't define it before you're ready to use it.
- don't `std::move` your return value, it prevents copy elision
- don't declare free functions `static`, it's a java thing
- inside `ReadMBR` there's a `char* buffer = new char[MBR_SIZE];` you don't use afterwards
- I'm not a fan of that many `using` directives; prefix the names with `std::` and be done with it, unless you prefer to set up aliases: then `using string = std::string` is clearer
- use standard algorithms, such as `std::copy`, `std::accumulate`, etc (in headers `<algorithm>` and `<numeric>`) or range-base for loops `(for auto item : sequence)` instead of "raw" loops. For instance, `charToHex` could be written

like this:

```
std::string s;
for (auto nibble : { (c >> 4) & 0xf, c & 0xf }) 
    s += fourBitsToString(nibble);
return s;
```

or:

```
char lo = c & 0xf;
char hi = (c >> 4) & 0xf;
char chars[] = {hi, lo};

return std::accumulate(std::begin(chars), std::end(chars), std::string(), [](auto init, auto elem) {
    return init += (fourBitsToString(elem));
});
```

And, on a more aesthetic note, a four-bits aggregate can be called a half-byte or a nibble.

Comment: "don't declare free functions `static`" - unless you want to explicitly restrict them to that specific translation unit (e.g. because it's an implementation detail not intended to be part of the public API). (This might also allow for better optimization, though I wouldn't suggest doing so just because of this reason.) // For printing, you suggest a call to `std::transform` with a `std::ostream_iterator` for `std::cout` and some custom logic also printing to `std::cout`. Methinks it would be cleaner to just use a `std::for_each` call and placing all printing logic into the lambda.

Comment: @hoffmale: if you want to restrict functions to a specific TU, an anonymous namespace is generally preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Release resources as soon as practical

The `diskHandle` should be released immediately after the `ReadFile` call to minimize the time that the handle is open.  Call `CloseHandle` to close the file and release the handle.

### Use minimal sufficient privileges

In this case, the MBR is only read and not written, so the file should be opened only with the `FILE_SHARE_READ` option and not `FILE_SHARE_WRTE`.

### Use `const` where practical

The `PrintMBR` function does not alter the passed `buffer` so the `buffer` parameter should be `const`.

### Use an object

I'm surprised that other reviews didn't mention this, but why not treat the MBR as a C++ object?  That way your `main` could look like this:

```
int main() {
    MBR mbr;
    if (mbr.read()) {
        std::cout << mbr << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error reading MBR\n";
    }
}
```

### Isolate platform-specific code

It would be very simple to write this code so that it also runs under Linux and doesn't rely on any particular compiler.  The easiest way to do that is to isolate the Windows-specific code so that it is easy to port.  This may not seem like a big deal if you're only interested in having a Windows version at the moment, but writing portable code by habit generally pays off in the long run in my experience.